# how to add columns label on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I can't understand how can I add column names on a pandas dataframe, an easy example will clarify my issue:

```
dic = {'a': [4, 1, 3, 1], 'b': [4, 2, 1, 4], 'c': [5, 7, 9, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

now if I type df than I get

```
   a  b  c
0  4  4  5
1  1  2  7
2  3  1  9
3  1  4  1
```

say now that I generate another dataframe just by summing up the columns on the previous one

```
a = df.sum()
```

if I type 'a' than I get

```
a     9
b    11
c    22
```

That looks like a dataframe without with index and without names on the only column. So I wrote

```
a.columns = ['column']
```

or

```
a.columns = ['index', 'column']
```

and in both cases Python was happy because he didn't provide me any message of errors. But still if I type 'a' I can't see the columns name anywhere. What's wrong here?

Comment: `sum` here returns `Series` not a df so there is no column as such

Comment: You can convert it to a dataframe `df.sum().to_frame('column')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `DataFrame.sum()` does an aggregation and therefore returns a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`. And a Series has no columns, only an index. If you want to create a DataFrame out of your sum you can change `a = df.sum()` by:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame(df.sum(), columns = ['whatever_name_you_want'])
```